# Is 'fullwidth commercial at' (unicode FF20) a good way to hide email addresses on web pages

Tags: email, unicode, spam-prevention

I am wondering whether writing my email address with a 'fullwidth commercial at' sign in stead of the normal @ is a good way to "hide" my email address from spam bots on the web?
E.g. `user＠domain.com`.

Comment: Probably not a bad idea, but unless you make a test and try, you won't know what harvesting bots really can and cannot decipher.

Comment: @slhck Where should I post such an email address to get it picked up efficiently?

Comment: On your website :) In all seriousness though, a better place to ask for spam protection might be [webmasters.SE], but make sure to check their existing questions and FAQ

Answer (score 0):

I think most email harvester bots are already programmed to match the most common email obfuscations.

Try here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots